# Maximum likelihood estimation without analytical form for noise?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, intractable-likelihood

I have a measured signal with additive noise that is sampled from a Rician distribution originally. For processing I divide the signal by the baseline measurement (first few points), and then end up taking the log of this signal to yield my final vector, y. I want to then use maximum likelihood to estimate the most likely set of parameters from my data. I know the model that maps parameters to to y (it's an integral equation).

My question is: Is it possible to calculate the maximum likelihood without an analytical form of the likelihood (and hence log-likelihood)? The reason is the noise pdf is quite complex. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you need an analytical or a computational solution? There are many **likelihood-free** estimation methods like approximate Bayesian computation and synthetic likelihood ...

Comment: Could you describe it in greater detail? There is no notion of "noise" in maximum likelihood, so do you mean the distribution of data as "noise" or maybe have in mind something specific like error-in-variables models? Also it's quite confusing as on one hand you seem to be saying that the distribution is parametric and known, on another that is not known.

Comment: Hello, I've modified the question a bit. In short, what I mean is my measured signal has its true component plus a noise sampled from a Rician distribution. The final signal I fit to a model gets transformed. I believe the PDF of the noise is where the likelihood function comes from, no?

Comment: For complex likelihoods, approximate Bayesian computation returns a Bayes estimate of sorts. The non-Bayesian version is indirect inference or the simulated method of moments.